# Braintree drop-in react paypal bug ppxo_no_token_passed_to_payment ppxo_unhandled_error

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to use the paypal drop-in through the braintree react drop-in library and I keep getting an error with the codes ppxo_no_token_passed_to_payment ppxo_unhandled_error in two separate errors.

my options passed to the initialization:

```js
const braintreeOptions = {
      authorization: braintreeApiKey,
      card: {
        cardholderName: {
          required: true,
        },
        overrides: {
          fields: {
            postalCode: null,
            number: {
              placeholder: null,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      paypal: {
        currency: 'USD',
        amount: total,
        flow: 'checkout',
        displayName: displayedPartnerName,
        locale: `${defaultLanguage}_${country}`,
      },
    };
```

`total` is a string of the total eg '25.00'

does anyone know what might be the issue?